# Can't run my scripts shell of my app after doing a rsync of data from Ubuntu server 18.04.5 LTS to another Ubuntu server 22.04.2?

Tags: server, bash, scripts, filesystem, rsync

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcoIx.png)I did an rsync of those filesystems
/home/
/opt/
/my_application/
/srv/

Did I forget to copy something else (...?), or is it a problem in version of Ubuntu ?
I need to run all scripts so i can exploit my App
thank you in advance

Comment: WIthout knowing what error messages, et.c your scripts are generating, or what your scripts' contents are, we cannot answer this at all.  Chances are though if your application is a compiled application you need to *recompile* the application against the libraries in 22.04 after transferring because between 2018 and 2022 there are major library changes.

Comment: there is no error messages while running scripts, i joined a pic of example of my script, my app is developped with C.
i need to recompile all scripts against the libraries please can anyone help me to proceed to it, I don't know the steps to focus on
thank you